# Changing predefined words in a biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

My university calls for a Harvard style and Biblatex style authoryear works well. For online sources it requires this

[image]

I have managed to change the standard URL: to '[Online]. Available at' with

```
\usepackage[minbibnames=1,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber,
style=authoryear,firstinits=true,dashed=false,natbib=true,url=true,
bibencoding=utf8,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refa.bib}% 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
urlseen = {Accessed}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{[Online]. Available at}\space\url{#1}}
```

But it is rendering as 
[image]

with text in bold and the first letter lower case, any ideas?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,british]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage[minbibnames=1,maxbibnames=99,maxcitenames=2,backend=biber,style=authoryear,
firstinits=true,dashed=false,natbib=true,url=true,bibencoding=utf8,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refa.bib}% 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen = {Accessed}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{[Online]. Available at}\space\url{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{schmitt_gradient_2013}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You must use `\bibstring{url}` and redefine the url string as you did with urlseen. (untested as you didn't provide a complete example).

Comment: Added a MWE. Tried the approach like urlseen but no joy.

Comment: @James Could you post your solution as an answer to the question? That way, it will be much clearer to anybody else who needs to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}% 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    urlseen = {Accessed}
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    urlseen = {Accessed},
    url = {[Online]. Available at}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{url}\space\url{#1}}

\begin{document}

\cite{ctan}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```