# Change predefined DOI label in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, doi

Having searched fairly thoroughly to solve this problem I came across this answer which solves the problem for URL:
[Changing predefined words in a biblatex bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202192/changing-predefined-words-in-a-biblatex-bibliography)

Is it possible to perform the same task on the DOI label to give the result shown below:

[image: Reference as it should look]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You'd like to replace `DOI` with what?

Comment: Having looked at my requirements I actually need to add the words `Available from:` immediately before the `DOI`. another option would be to change the whole sequence to `Available from: doi:`

Comment: I have edited to show a picture of what is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\xpatchfieldformat{doi}{\mkbibacro{DOI}}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\mkbibacro{DOI}}{}{}
```

or, as suggested by @Moewe:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchfieldformat{doi}{\mkbibacro{DOI}}{\mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space\bibstring{urlfrom}}{}{}
```

Comment: Excellent, I don't have much experience of xpatch but it is working well. I will have to read up on it.

Comment: The longest job is to find where the stuff is defined. Actually I'd like to have the possibility to ‘ internationalise’ the code, as ‘ Available from’ is just the bibstring `urlfrom`, but could find no place in the code where it was used, so I don't know  how to call it.

Comment: What about `\xpatchfieldformat{doi}{\mkbibacro{DOI}}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\mkbibacro{DOI}}{}{}`? Note that normally, I would not advise to patch field formats as they are often short enough to simply change the entire thing, in this case, I have to admit that `\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}` (modulo line breaks) is a bit long. (I also think we're over-using the colon here a fair bit, but OK.)

Comment: @Moewe: Thank you for recalling me the `\bibstring` command. I've modified the code accordingly and added your variant suggestion.

Comment: I have added @moewe longer answer to my biblatex.cfg

Comment: I just noted that in the second suggestion now the order of `\mkbibacro{DOI}` and `\bibstring{urlfrom}` seems switched ...

Comment: @moewe: They are. Isn't it what you you suggested?

Comment: @Bernard Did I?